# Upgrading network-manager crashes sudo

Tags: networking, upgrade, debian

When I try to apt-get upgrade and it's setting up the network-manager, nothing happens until it gets exited via time-out.

After the notification that it's setting up I can't use any sudo commands , the internet doesn't work anymore and the i3bar doesn't refresh. If I try to shutdown my laptop it takes nearly 20 minutes to do so, because it runs a stop job "for session 2 of $User" for different network machines e.g printers.

After a restart it works fine until I try to upgrade again. Sometimes I get the message "dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem when trying to upgrade again after a restart. But this will only try to set up the network-manager again, so the problem continues.
This will happen on wifi and ethernet.

```
Setting up network-manager (1.10.0-1) ...
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl  status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for 
details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript network-manager, action "restart" failed.
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: timeout) since Sun 2017-11-
26 16:10:41 CET; 14ms ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 6520
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─6520 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 26 16:10:41 debian systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with 
result 'timeout'.
Nov 26 16:10:41 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
 installed network-manager package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you run ´sudo dpkg --configure -a´ as suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did. Then it tries to set up the network-manager again and causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In that case (unless you want to remove `NetworkManager` and replace it by something else) you'll need to fix `NetworkManager`.

For one thing, you could have a look at `journalctl  -xe` does it show you anything useful?

Second thing is you could do is to "reproduce the problem manually", i.e. issue `service NetworkManager restart` as root. Does that show you something interesting?

If that doesn't show you anything interesting either, then try to "restart" `NetworkManager` even more "manually". I.e. have a look at the NetworkManager service. It should be living under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service` or such. On my system that file tells me that `systemd` will:

- try to stop `NetworkManager` by `kill -TERM $PID_OF_NETWORK_MANAGER`
- try to start `NetworkManager` by executing `NetworkManager --no-daemon`

What you can do now is to do that manually. I.e. try to do the kill manually to stop `NetworkManager` and try to start it manually by running the command above. Note that `NetworkManager` supports a `--debug` flag, which you could use to see more verbose output from `NetworkManager`, which could tell you what it exactly is that makes `NetworkManager` either to take so long to stop or take that long to start. I.e. what `NetworkManager` is waiting for to happen...

Also note, that on my system `systemd` expects `NetworkManager` to appear on `dbus`. So you could check that as well.

Comment: In my `NetworkManager.service` file the line `ExecReload=\bin\kill -HUP $MAINPID` was commented out. Instead, it used `dbus-send`. Changing it didn't help.    
Also, I can't kill the process and restart it since I can't use sudo after killing it. When I try to start it when it's already running, I get this output: 
`...
<error> [1511787928.0468] bus-manager: could not acquire the NetworkManager service as it is already taken
<error> [1511787928.0469] failed to start the dbus service.
<info>  [1511787928.0849] exiting (error)`.

Comment: First - if you google that error you find people with the same problem. Could any of the solutions that people have found to that problem bring you any further? Second - you could try doing a `strace` of `sudo` and seeing where it gets stuck - it looks like it gets stuck on the network. Why that? What is `sudo` trying to do and getting stuck? Maybe doing a DNS lookup of the host name of the local machine? Can the machine resolve it's own name and IP? Are the respective entries in `/etc/hosts`?